# Append form values to jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to post a from values to a remote API  via AJAX.

I need the `author`,  `string`, `false`, `true` from the HTML form element.

Right now I have hardcored to values bu

```
function sendData() {
  var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "timeout":8000,

          "url": "http://localhost:8984/solr/techproducts/schema",
          "method": "POST",

          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"

          },
          "processData": false,
          "data": "{\"replace-field\":{\"name\":\"author\",\"type\":\"string\",\"stored\":false,\"indexed\":true} }"
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Comment: I wanted to get the values of those from a HTML form.

Comment: You can set ids to html fields and access them  `$("#idOfNeededField").val()`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var requestData = {
    id : $('#id').val(),
    commentLiveStatusStageChange:$('#'+textid).val(),
    currentLiveStatusStage:$('#stage').val()
}

 var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "timeout":8000,

          "url": "http://localhost:8984/solr/techproducts/schema",
          "method": "POST",

          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"

          },
          "processData": false,
          "data": requestData 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize the formdata and then append it.

Ex:
`formData = $("#myForm").serialize()`

Then use formdata in ajax request

```
function sendData() {
  formData = $("#myForm").serialize() //myForm should be replaced with your form's id
  var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "timeout":8000,

          "url": "http://localhost:8984/solr/techproducts/schema",
          "method": "POST",

          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"

          },
          "processData": false,
          "data": formData
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$( "form" ).serialize();` Something like this to post your form values:

```
  $.post( "http://localhost:8984/solr/techproducts/schema", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```